# Can I change a URL using EditText and Button?

Tags: android

Here's the code that I want to change

```
private void updateQuestion() { 
    mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://fdbfdb-d7cbb.firebaseio.com/"+
        mQuestionNumber +"/question");
}
```

So can I add an EditText and Button beside it and the button will change the link (`https://fdbfdb-d7cbb.firebaseio.com/`) according to the value of the EditText, is that possible?

Comment: a link is a String and you can set a String if you want, just use a placeholder for the link an inizialize it with your origin link. When the Button is pressed you can change the Link to whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes obviously it's possible. Build the url during run time like keep your base url on a variable, and concat other part of url from edittext on button click then make network call or whatever you want.

String baseUrl = "https://fdbfdb-d7cbb.firebaseio.com/";
private void onClick(){
 updateQuestion(edittext.getText().toString()) //Check edittext empty or not before this line
}
//////OR//////
 private void updateQuestion(String number) 
{ mQuestionRef = new Firebase(baseUrl+ number +"/question");
}

private void updateQuestion() 
{ 
    mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://fdbfdb-d7cbb.firebaseio.com/"+ edittext.text.toString() +"/question");

}

Comment: Thanks for this understood this very well. sorry for late response quite busy these days thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse

Method
private void updateQuestion(String questionNo) { mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://fdbfdb-d7cbb.firebaseio.com/"+ questionNo+"/question");

}
Method usage 
First convert your edit text into string like
String question = edittext.text.toString()

UpdateQuestion(question)

Now call the function on your button click or any where you want

Comment: Thanks ! this helped